# git or svn for web server?

Tags: svn, git

What's better to put on a web server? I'm new to Revision Control so I wouldn't know. Also this project exists already but I would like to implement some revision control on it and put it on a web server because there are multiple people that work on the code and multiple computers. Thanks!

Comment: I think this should be Community wiki, elseqay it's likely to be closed (argumentative,...)

Answer (score 3):

Use git. It is not harder to learn than SVN if you do not have any version control knowledge. It has some really awesome helper tools and built-in commands.

There are multiple ways to make your workflow with git. There are really good blogposts on the Internet if you search for `git workflow`.

Answer (score 2):

The trend these days is GIT over SVN. If you are looking for a hosted service, check out http://github.com/.

Comment: Can I set up something like github on my own server because my data files are huge and I don't want to pay github for a private repository? Thanks!

Comment: @ranzy: you can host Gitosis yourself.

Comment: @ranzy Gitosis is a good option. Just remember that in hosting any repositories, you must setup a backup policy on your server. Also, GitHub doesn't have any file size limits (just repository count limits). If you have a legitimate reason to use lots of storage, they won't keep you from doing so.

Comment: Oh okay. It's just that I don't want to host on Github because the stuff I'm working on is not open source so I don't want anybody to see.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely Git. If you read about its architecture and the way it works (through on-line books, there are several), you'll understand that it's ages ahead of subversion or cvs (yikes). Plus, it's super fast.

Comment: Do you recommend any others such as mercurial or bazaar or git will do? Thanks!

Comment: No. Git will do just fine. Just be sure to read about the way it works (unstaged, staged, committed, etc.), understand the notion of branches and that each user has effectively their own branch, regardless of using remote repositories or not. Check the Pro Git online book (http://progit.org/book/).

Answer (score 0):

Use subversion if you're new to version control. Lots of tutorials available to help you setup